# Demonstrating that $\sum_{n=0}^{50}i^n=i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I got this summation and need to demonstrate why the result is $i$. Any ideas?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{50}i^n=i$$

Comment: What is the sum of the first four terms?  ... the first eight?

Comment: The sum of the first four is 0

Comment: We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions, please edit your question and add in what you have tried so far so we can help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with powers of $i$, the following are important:

$i^1 = i$,
$i^2 = -1$,
$i^3 = -i$,
$i^4 = 1$,

So, $i$ raised to any power greater than $4$ can be written in terms of these 4 terms. For example, $i^5$ can be written as $i^4 \cdot i = i$. Now, when you try to find the the values of every four terms in the summation (starting from $n = 1$) , you will realise that the sum of every four terms is $0$. So,

$\sum_{n=1}^{4}i^n=0$, $\sum_{n=5}^{8}i^n=0$, $\sum_{n=9}^{12}i^n=0$, and so on..

Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{48}i^n=0$

Now that we've dealt with $48$ terms, we are left with the $0^{th}$, $49^{th}$ and $50^{th}$, which are $1, -1$ and $i$ respectively.

$1-1+i = i$

Thus,

$\sum_{n=0}^{50}i^n= 1 +\sum_{n=1}^{48}i^n -1 +i = i$

Answer (score 2):

First, this is simply a brain teaser than a linear algebra problem. Note that $i$ imaginary number has the following traits: $i^2=-1$, $i^3=-i$ and $i^4=1$. Given this, Note that summation of all even indices of $n=4*j$ where $j$ some non-negative integers and $n=4*j+2$ are going to cancel each other out up to $n=50$. This means even terms will give you $0$ contribution to the sum. Now consider odd-numbered indices, then you know that there are $25$ odd terms that cancel each other out because they are alternating $-i$ and $i$ except one term is not canceled. Odd indexed terms then contribute $i$ to the sum. Hence, you end up with a total sum of $i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$i^0+i^1+i^2+i^3=1+i-1-i=0$$
$$i^4+i^5+i^6+i^7=1+i-1-i=0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$i^{44}+i^{45}+i^{46}+i^{47}=1+i-1-i=0$$
$$i^{48}+i^{49}+i^{50}=1+i-1=i$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $i^2=-1,i^3=-i,i^4=1$, every 4 consecative terms cancle out.

So$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{50}i^n=\sum\limits_{n=48}^{50}i^n=1+i+i^2=i$

Answer (score 1):

Geometric series:

$S_{50}=\dfrac{1-i^{51}}{1-i}=$

$(1/2))(1-i^{51})(1+i) =$

$(1/2)(1+i)^2=i.$

Used:
$i^{51}=i^{48}i^3=1(-i)$